# Is there a way to capture keystrokes in Python and filter out those generated by key repeat?

Tags: python, macos, input, keyboard-events

I'm experimenting with some input methods in Python, and using `pynput` I have a simple grabber for keys being pressed and released, just like in the docs:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def on_press(key):
    print('{0} pressed'.format(
        key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} release'.format(
        key))
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

However, on_press is called regardless of whether the key was generated by a key repeating or just the key being pressed and as far as I can tell, I cannot know which it is.

Is there a way to at know? My target platform is macOS, but this should hopefully work on Windows as well as I may want to port this idea some day.

`pynput` is nice, but I don't mind switching libraries if it means I can get what I need for this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of a key repeat event (at least on my Ubuntu system) additional key-press events are generated/simulated without intervening key-release events:

```
$ python keypress_vs_repeat.py 
Key.enter release
a'a' pressed
a'a' pressed
a'a' pressed
a'a' pressed
a'a' release
```

You can use that information to distinguish a real key-press from a simulated key-press:

**keypress_vs_repeat.py**

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

currently_pressed_key = None

def on_press(key):
    global currently_pressed_key
    if key == currently_pressed_key:
        print('{0} repeated'.format(key))
    else:
        print('{0} pressed'.format(key))
        currently_pressed_key = key

def on_release(key):
    global currently_pressed_key
    print('{0} release'.format(key))
    currently_pressed_key = None
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

**Testing** (press <kbd>a</kbd> once, press and hold <kbd>b</kbd>):

```
$ python keypress_vs_repeat.py
Key.enter release
'a' pressed
a'a' release
'b' pressed
b'b' repeated
b'b' repeated
b'b' repeated
b'b' repeated
b'b' repeated
b'b' release
Key.esc pressed
^[Key.esc release
^[$
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on OS X and Mint. I do not have Windows to test:

```
class _Getch:
    """Gets a single character from standard input.  Does not echo to the
screen."""
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.impl = _GetchWindows()
        except ImportError:
            self.impl = _GetchUnix()
    def __call__(self): return self.impl()

class _GetchUnix:
    def __init__(self):
        import tty, sys

    def __call__(self):
        import sys, tty, termios
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
        return ch

class _GetchWindows:
    def __init__(self):
        import msvcrt

    def __call__(self):
        import msvcrt
        return msvcrt.getch()

getch = _Getch()
```

Test:

```
c=getch()
i=1
while c!='q':
    c=getch()
    print c, i
    # if key is held, it does not repeat...
    i+=1
```

Based on [this ActiveState recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/)